# Trying to make a django rest api that doesn't look like my models

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to make an API for an outside group where I define user access.  I have a setup in django that makes it easy to administer, but I would like the output to be quite simplistic for the other team.

This is the output I'm looking for would be something like:

```
{
    "user_list": {
        "user": {
            "username": "username1",
            "top_accesses": ["top_access_1", "top_access_2", "top_access_5"],
            "middle_accesses": ["middle_access_1", "middle_access_2", "middle_access_7"],
            "lower_accesses": ["lower_access_1", "lower_access_2", "lower_access_22"],
        },
        "user": {
            "username": "username2",
            "top_accesses": ["top_access_1", "top_access_2", "top_access_8"],
            "middle_accesses": ["middle_access_3", "middle_access_5", "middle_access_6"],
            "lower_accesses": ["lower_access_21", "lower_access_33", "lower_access_36"],
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm having trouble using django's built in ORM to come up with these sets from my models.  I can think of how to do it in SQL, but this isn't a particularly clean method.  I know there must be a better way to do it since using TabularInline shows exactly what I want to see in the admin page

Here are my models:

```
class TopAccess(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    site_user_access = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
    site_group_access = models.ManyToManyField(Group, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Top Access"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class MiddleAccess(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    site_user_access = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
    site_group_access = models.ManyToManyField(Group, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Middle Access"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class LowerAccess(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    site_user_access = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
    site_group_access = models.ManyToManyField(Group, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Lower Access"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Ideally I would be able to return a query object that plays well with the django-rest-framework in the end, since I like how nicely it returns the same data in whichever form is requested

**Edit**:
This is what I'm thinking is going to be close to the solution, but I know I'm using class inheritance incorrectly

```
class MaybeThisCouldWork(User):
    t_user = TopAccess.objects.filter(site_user_access=User)
    m_user = MiddleAccess.objects.filter(site_user_access=User)
    l_user = LowerAccess.objects.filter(site_user_access=User)
    user_groups = User.objects.filter(id=User)
    for user_group in user_groups:
        t_group = TopAccess.objects.filter(
                site_group_access=user_groups
                )
        m_group = MiddleAccess.objects.filter(
                site_group_access=user_groups
                )
        l_group = LowerAccess.objects.filter(
                site_group_access=user_groups
                )
        t_user = t_user | t_group
        m_user = m_user | m_group
        l_user = l_user | l_group
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use serializers, may be something like this,

```
class TopAccessSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TopAccess
        fields = ['name']

class MiddleAccessSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MiddleAccess
        fields = ['name']

class LowerAccessSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = LowerAccess
        fields = ['name']


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    topaccess = TopAccessSerializer(source='topaccess_set', many=True)
    middleaccess = MiddleAccessSerializer(source='middleaccess_set', many=True)
    loweraccess = LowerAccessSerializer(source='loweraccess_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'topaccess', 'middleaccess', 'loweraccess']
```

Comment: This looks very promising, I'm going to give it a try right now.  I'll let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: The real magic hers is the 'loweraccess_set ' property. I didn't know that existed (I'm pretty new to django).  That is the exact parameter I was looking for.  Thanks so much!

Comment: That's reverse relation accessor in django ForeignKey relations. You may look up them in docs here.. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward